# Java, Get Class object for containing class, Not Runtime Class

Tags: java, reflection, oop

Consider this Java code

```
class A{
 //@returns Class object this method is contained in
 // should be A in this case
 public Class<?> f() {
   return getClass();
 }
}

class B extends A {}

B b = new B();

System.out.println(b.f());
//output -- B.class (Wrong, should be A.class)
```

inside `f()` i can't use `getClass()` because that will give me the runtype, which is `B`. I'm looking for a way to get the `Class` object of the `class` `f()` is inside (Without mentioning `A` explicitly, obviously)

Comment: Why don't you want to mention A explicitly? `A.class` seems like the most straightforward solution.

Comment: I think if you have to figure out which exact type your instance is during runtime, gives a strong signal that some refactoring or rethinking needs to be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use exception stack trace facility to do something like this:

```
public String f() {
    Exception E = new Exception();
    E.fillInStackTrace();
    return E.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName(); // load it if you need to return class
}
```

Comment: You don't need exception to get stacktrace. This is much better way: Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work. Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() populates the stack trace with Thread's own methods - dumpThreads() and getStackTrace() itself, though it possibly differs depending on JVM version / implementation.

Comment: The only difference is that Thread's stack trace has one more element. Just use getStackTrace()[1];

Comment: Two more elements in java 1.5; and that may change depending on implementation. Now you can definitely go through stack trace and exclude all elements whose class is java.lang.Thread but at that point it's no longer easy and elegant; using exception seems easier.

Answer (score 6):

`new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingClass()`. But please don't!

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say it would be much simpler and more clear to simply return A.class as @mmyers suggested.  There is not much point in trying to derive it at runtime if you don't actually want the runtime value.  The only issue that comes up is if you refactor the name of the class and another with the same name happens to exist, in the same package.

I would take that chance for the sake of clarity in the code now.

Comment: Exactly. The derivative answers are over-complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
class.getMethod("f",parameterTypes).getDeclaringClass()
```

Comment: This will only work for public methods; plus it's rather messy dealing with parameters.

Comment: You're both right. The approach using a stack trace is probably better. And of course it should be getClass (fixed). f need not be final however. Why should it need to be?

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you didn't want to mention A.class explicitly

```
class A {        
    public Class<?> f() {
        return A.class;
    }   
}
```

but I'm struggling to find a use case where the above code isn't satisfactory.